# Transparency and Alpha levels for ggplot2 stat_density2d with maps and layers in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, visualization

Can anyone offer suggestions as to the best way to deal with transparency and alpha levels with many layers (with reference to `ggplot2`)?  In the sample code below, it becomes very difficult to see individual state borderlines (e.g. South Carolina, North Carolina, Virginia) -- I have tried setting `alpha=0.00001` but this appears to make things worse...

```
library(ggplot2)

all_states = map_data("state")
set.seed(103)
df = data.frame(long=sample(-90:-70,100,T), lat=sample(30:45,100,T))
p = ggplot() + 
    geom_polygon(data=all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="white", fill="grey80") + 
    stat_density2d(data=df, aes(x=long, y=lat, fill=..level.., alpha=..level..), # HELP HERE ???
                   size=2, bins=5, geom='polygon') +
    geom_point(data=df, aes(x=long, y=lat), 
               color="coral1", position=position_jitter(w=0.4,h=0.4), alpha=0.8) + 
    theme_bw()
p
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you map some variable to `alpha=` inside the `aes()` then by default alpha values range from 0.1 to 1 (0.1 for lowest maped variable values and 1 for highest values). You can change it with `scale_alpha_continuous()` and setting different maximal and minimal range values.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
               color="white", fill="grey80") + 
  stat_density2d(data=df, aes(x=long, y=lat, fill=..level.., alpha=..level..), 
                 size=2, bins=5, geom='polygon') +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=long, y=lat), 
             color="coral1", position=position_jitter(w=0.4,h=0.4), alpha=0.8) + 
  theme_bw()+
  scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0.1,0.5))
```

[image]