# Coordinate points appropriately sized in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have sampled 10,000 coordinates from my data in this file. I have around 130,000 points.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/40hfyx6a5hsjuv7/data.csv

I am trying to plot these points on the Americas map using ggplot2. Here is my code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

map_world <- map_data("world")
map_world <- subset(map_world, (lat >= -60 & lat <= 75))
map_world <- subset(map_world, (long >= -170 & long <= -30))

p <- ggplot(data = data_coords, legend = FALSE) +
geom_polygon(data = map_world, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat), shape = 19, size = 0.00001,
           alpha = 0.3, colour = "red") +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
xlab("") + ylab("")

png("my_plot.png", width = 8000, height = 7000, res = 1000)
print(p)
dev.off()
```

[image]

The points seem to cover the whole area in which they were plotted. I would like them to be more smaller to better represent a location. You can see that I've set the size to 0.00001. I was just trying to see if it has any effect but it doesn't seem to help after a certain limit. Is this the best that is possible at this resolution or could it be reduced more?

I had actually plotted around 400,000 points but only on the US map before and they looked much better like below. Hoping to get something like this. Thanks.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8d0niu9g6ygz0wo/Clusters_reduced.png

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with very small values of alpha, instead of the point size:

http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_point.html

```
# Varying alpha is useful for large datasets
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price))
d + geom_point(alpha = 1/1000)
```

**Edit:**

Additional ideas are given in the documentation. Here's a summary:

**Details**

The scatterplot is useful for displaying the relationship between two continuous variables, although it can also be used with one continuous and one categorical variable, or two categorical variables. See `geom_jitter` for possibilities.

The bubblechart is a scatterplot with a third variable mapped to the size of points. There are no special names for scatterplots where another variable is mapped to point shape or colour, however.

The biggest potential problem with a scatterplot is **overplotting**: whenever you have more than a few points, points may be plotted on top of one another. This can severely distort the visual appearance of the plot. There is no one solution to this problem, but there are some techniques that can help. You can add additional information with `stat_smooth`, `stat_quantile` or `stat_density2d`. If you have few unique x values, geom_boxplot may also be useful. Alternatively, you can summarise the number of points at each location and display that in some way, using `stat_sum`.

Another technique is to use transparent points, geom_point(alpha = 0.05).

Edit 2:

Combining the details from the manual with the hints in [Transparency and Alpha levels for ggplot2 stat_density2d with maps and layers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193138/transparency-and-alpha-levels-for-ggplot2-stat-density2d-with-maps-and-layers-in)

This might look like the solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

data_coords <- read.csv("C:/Downloads/data.csv")

map_world <- map_data("world")
map_world <- subset(map_world, (lat >= -60 & lat <= 75))
map_world <- subset(map_world, (long >= -170 & long <= -30))

p <- ggplot(     data = data_coords, legend = FALSE) +
 geom_polygon(   data = map_world, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
 stat_density2d( data = data_coords, aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill = as.factor(..level..)), size=1, bins=10, geom='polygon') +
 scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","red","green","royalblue", "black","white","orange","brown","grey"))

png("my_plot2k.png", width = 2000, height = 2000, res = 500)
print(p)
dev.off()
```

Resulting image (not the best colour palette used):

[image: Contour-Plot-Image]

Comment: I am already using alpha. A large point size even with an alpha shows a coverage which is not representative of the coverage of a single coordinate on the map. Hence my need to reduce point size.

Comment: What happens if you reduce alpha to 10 times smaller number?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. I will have to plot density if point size doesn't work. But what I am wondering is if there is a limit to the size of a point at a certain resolution. My plot has 8000 X 7000 pixels. I should be able to represent a point as a pixel or a bit greater. How can I achieve that size?

Comment: Any new discoveries from your side? I didn't have time yet to go further into the pixel-detail story...