# Heatmap Transparency, Coloring and Specificity not Satisfying

Tags: r, heatmap, ggmap

```
v <- 2^(7:17)
min_lon <- 6.164780
max_lon <- 15.744857
min_lat <- 47.228296
max_lat <- 54.426407
center_lon <- (min_lon + max_lon)/2
center_lat <- (min_lat + max_lat)/2

df <- data.frame(id = 1:sum(v))
df$T <- rep(paste("T", v, sep="_"), v)
df$lon <- runif(sum(v),min_lon, max_lon)
df$lat <- runif(sum(v),min_lat,max_lat)
```

**Making a heatmap with transparency=..level..**

```
gg_heatmap <- function(T){
    g <- ggmap(get_map(location=c(lat=center_lat, lon=center_lon), zoom=6, maptype="roadmap", source="google"))
    g <- g + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(rainbow(100, start=0, end=0.75)))
    g <- g + stat_density2d(data=df[df$T == "T_1024",], aes(x = lon, y = lat,fill = ..level..,transparency=..level..), 
                            size=1, bins=100, geom = 'polygon')
    print(g)
}

system.time(gg_heatmap("T_1024"))
```

[image]

**Making a heatmap by setting alpha = .05**

```
gg_heatmap <- function(T){
    g <- ggmap(get_map(location=c(lat=center_lat, lon=center_lon), zoom=6, maptype="roadmap", source="google"))
    g <- g + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(rainbow(100, start=0, end=0.75)))
    g <- g + stat_density2d(data=df[df$T == "T_1024",], aes(x = lon, y = lat,fill = ..level..), alpha=.05,
                            size=1, bins=100, geom = 'polygon')
    print(g)
}

system.time(gg_heatmap("T_1024"))
```

[image]

Both results aren't satisfying. I would prefer to see something like the following heatmap made with QlikView and using the same data set "T_1024".

[image]

**There are three aspects I prefer about the QV-version:**

1. The transparency allows to still see the map underneath ...
2. ... while the colors are still expressive and not pale
3. The coloring allows to indentify more details

I tried to tackle (1) by experimenting with different ways of setting the alpha level statically as well as relative to ..level.. Yet I could not get good results. The transparency is never really good and if I see the map the colors too pale.

(3) I thought I could influence by setting a high bin value.

**Any ideas how to optimize the heatmap rendering or at least aspects of it?**

Comment: Is `transparency` a valid argument to `stat_density2d(...)`?? Why aren't you using `alpha=..level..`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note: credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193138/transparency-and-alpha-levels-for-ggplot2-stat-density2d-with-maps-and-layers-in) for the basic structure of the answer.

This produces a heatmap wherein the contours are clearly distinguished, and the map below is visible. The main differences to your code are:

1. Removed `size=...` and `bins=...` arguments. There is no need for `size` (it does nothing here).
2. Replace `transparency=..levels..` (what is that??), with `alpha=..levels..`.
3. Add `scale_alpha_continuous(...)`, setting the range limits in alpha and turning off the alpha guide.

.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
gg_heatmap <- function(){
  g <- ggmap(get_map(location=c(lat=center_lat, lon=center_lon), zoom=6, maptype="roadmap", source="google"))
  g <- g + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(rainbow(100, start=0, end=0.75)))
  g <- g + stat_density2d(data=df[df$T == "T_1024",], aes(x = lon, y = lat,fill = ..level..,alpha=..level..), 
                           geom = 'polygon')
  g <- g +   scale_alpha_continuous(guide="none",range=c(0,.4))
  print(g)
}
gg_heatmap()
```

[image]

Note that I used `set.seed(1)` prior to creating `df` for a reproducible example. You'll need to add that if you want the same plot.

**EDIT** Response to OP's comment.

`stat_density2d(...)` works by defining contours and drawing filled polygons to enclose them, so by definition the contours will be "edgy". If you want to fuzz out the contours, you will probably have to use a tiling approach. Unfortunately, this requires calculating the 2D kernal density estimates outside of `ggplot`:

```
gg_heatmap <- function(T){
  require(MASS)
  require(ggplot2)
  require(ggmap)
  d <- with(df[df$T==T,], kde2d(lon,lat,h=c(1.5,1.5),n=100))
  d.df <- expand.grid(lon=d[[1]],lat=d[[2]])
  d.df$z <- as.vector(d$z)
  g <- ggmap(get_map(location=c(lat=center_lat, lon=center_lon), zoom=6, maptype="roadmap", source="google"))
  g <- g + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(rainbow(100, start=0, end=0.75)))
  g <- g + geom_tile(data=d.df, aes(x=lon,y=lat,fill=z),alpha=.8)
  print(g)
}
gg_heatmap("T_1024")
```

[image]

From the standpoint of data visualization, this plot is distinctly inferior to the first one. Whether it's "prettier" or not is a matter of opinion.

Comment: thank you very much for your insights. nonetheless with all due respect, sir, your heatmap looks pretty ugly :) getting something good looking is central to my question. at least I can see the map - but I don't like the edginess of the contours at all.

Comment: It is most certainly *not* my goal to create something you find "pretty". The goal should be to create a visualization that most clearly conveys the information content in the dataset. See my edits.

Comment: well - but given that a heatmap is the visualization of a real-valued smooth function (the density) a not-edgy-coloring does not just look more pretty it is also mathematically more acurate. but thanks for the explanation as to why using a polygon-geometry tends to give a more edgy result. but why the second more pretty approach is inferior from a data viz perspective I am still curious to learn about.