# Trying to create heat map using ggplot similar to density / contour plot, but where color scale is based on continuous variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm using baseball pitch data and trying to create plots that look something like these:

[image]
[image]

The x and y coordinates are the exact same in my data as they are below, while my continuous variable called HPOE ranges from about -.05:2. Here's a link to one of the data sets I'm trying to create a plot for:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oy9tu1vfqnd9fax/sample_plot_data.csv?dl=0

I've tried a number of things, and I'm maybe searching for a solution using the wrong terminology but nothing I've tried quite works.
stat_density2d only shows density, returning error "The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: z". Ignoring color scale, this is how I'd want the plot to look.

```
stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..), contour=TRUE, geom="polygon") +
geom_segment(y = mean(pc_filt$sz_bot), yend = mean(pc_filt$sz_bot), x = -0.89, xend = 0.89, color = "black", size = 1.25) +
geom_segment(y = mean(pc_filt$sz_top), yend = mean(pc_filt$sz_top), x = -0.89, xend = 0.89, color = "black", size = 1.25) +
geom_segment(y = mean(pc_filt$sz_bot), yend = mean(pc_filt$sz_top), x = -0.89, xend = -0.89, color = "black", size = 1.25) +
geom_segment(y = mean(pc_filt$sz_bot), yend = mean(pc_filt$sz_top), x = 0.89, xend = 0.89, color = "black", size = 1.25)
```

[image]

geom_tile isn't terrible, but after trying different tile sizes and color scales it really just doesn't do what I'd like it to. geom_raster had similar results.

```
  geom_tile(aes(fill = hpoe), width = 0.5, height = 0.25, alpha = 0.25) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "white")
```

[image]

This plot is probably the most helpful, but still not what I'm looking for:

```
  stat_summary_hex(bins=10) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", high = "blue", mid = "white")
```

[image]

Comment: What do you get when you use `ggplot(YourData, aes(x = YourXVar, y = YourYVar)) + stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE)`? I think you may want `..density..`. Also see here: https://r-graphics.org/recipe-distribution-density2d . If you want rainbow colors, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842031/heatmap-transparency-coloring-and-specificity-not-satisfying

Comment: @David Your code provides another density plot; when I add a fill argument for my continuous variable it changes the legend title on the side but still provides the same exact density plot unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your clarification @ChazC.  I think what you're looking for is a 2D contour plot with `x`, `y`, `z` data, where `z` is `hpoe`.  What makes this a harder problem is that you have irregularly-spaced data, such that your data does not fall on a complete grid.  In this case, we need some interpolation for bivariate data.  One way to attempt this is to use the `akima` library.

I read in your data and called it `mlb`.

```
#order it by plate_x
mlb <- mlb[order(mlb$plate_x),]

> head(mlb)
     plate_x plate_z       hpoe
100    -2.60    2.66 0.03583419
439    -2.34    3.00 0.04082628
559    -2.09    5.15 0.06027308
542    -1.94    5.53 0.03120266
1363   -1.77    1.91 0.03017583
1145   -1.76    4.52 0.02527670

#load akima for interpolation
library(akima)

#do the interpolation on irregularly-spaced grid
#extrap is necessary, and duplicate handles the duplicate values in your data
fld <- with(mlb, interp(x = plate_x, y = plate_z, z = hpoe, 
         duplicate = "median", extrap = T))
#make a data frame from this list and remove NAs
df <- melt(fld$z, na.rm = TRUE)
#rename for clarity
names(df) <- c("x", "y", "z")
#backfill the x and y values to make the correct axis ticks instead of default integer grid points
df$x <- fld$x[df$x]
df$y <- fld$y[df$y]
#now plot
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) +
  stat_contour() +
  xlab("plate_x") +
  ylab("plate_z") +
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "HPOE", low = "white", high = "blue")
```

[image: hpoe contour ggplot]

Note that white regions are below the `hpoe = 0` plane.

Your data seems to have too many spikes for contour plots to be easily interpretable.  This surface plot hopefully demonstrates this.  This is only my opinion, though.

[image: hpoe surface]